# It is possible to create two graphic terminals in one computer?

Tags: lubuntu, screen, kvm-virtualization

I have a computer with two screens, and I want to share it with my daugther. If I attach two mice and two keyboard, can the computer be configured so each screen is like an independent computer?

I have a couple of ideas about how to solve this:

1. Use kvm to virtualize the machine, install two OSes and bind each one to a screen, keyboard and mouse (I don't know if this is possible)
2. A standard Lubuntu (or *Ubuntu) installation, and setup with 2 X servers, one on each screen.

Has anyone build something like this? Do you know any tutorial about how to do this?

Comment: One possible solution: if you don't want to operate on two screens simultaneously. Create two workspaces and operate two different workspaces on two different screens. Same mouse, keyboard can be used for this and you can run different applications on different screens.

Comment: But I don't want to use the two screens as if they were the same screen, what I want is to use the two screens as if they were two different computers, with two mice and two keyboards, different users, etc.

Comment: "multiseat" is the name for what you are looking for. Oh and you probably also need 2 grahics cards or 1 with 2 heads.

Comment: this might come closest to a how to: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiseatTeam/Instructions

Comment: @Rinzwind: That's great! It's exactly what I was looking for! Can you publish your comments as an answer, so I can upvote you?

Comment: I would if I could test it... If you want you can make it your own answer whilst you are setting this up :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is multiseatX installation. several users with their own keyboard, mouse and display on the same computer. [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX)

Comment: This might be of assistance: http://2buntu.com/articles/1514/multiseat-in-ubuntu-1410/